# How do I halt this setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This loops forever, how do I stop it at the marked location?

```
$.fn.writeText = function(content) {
    var contentArray = content.split(""),
        current = 0,
        elem = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        if(current < contentArray.length) {
            elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);   
        }
        else{
            //stop here.
        }
    }, 100);

};

$("#ID").writeText("Texty text text");
```

Thanks. I think it's supposed to be clearTimeout(), but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Have you checked here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#Example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clearTimeout()` as shown :-

```
$.fn.writeText = function(content) {
    var timer;
    var contentArray = content.split(""),
        current = 0,
        elem = this;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        if(current < contentArray.length) {
            elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);   
        }
        else{
           clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }, 100);

};

$("#ID").writeText("Texty text text");
```